# OCaml: Combination of elements in Lists, functional reasoning

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, automata

I am back to coding in OCaml and I missed it so much. I missed it so much I completely lost my reasoning in this language and I hit a wall today.

What I want to do is the combination of elements between a set of n lists.
I decomposed the problem by first attempting the combination of elements between two list of arbitrary sizes.

Assume we have to lists: `l1 = [1;2;3]` and `l2 = [10,20]`.

What I want to do is obtain the following list:

```
 l_res = [10;20;20;40;30;60]
```

I know how to do this using loop structures, but I really want to solve this without them.

I tried the following:

```
       let f l1 l2 = 
         List.map (fun y -> (List.map (fun x -> x * y) l1) l2
```

But this does not seem to work. The type I get is `f : int list -> int list -> int list list` but I want `f : int list -> int list -> int list`

I tried already many different approaches I feel I am over complicating.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is that `List.map f [a; b; c]` gives `[f a; f b; f c]` so what you'll get from your function will be

```
f [a; b; c] [d; e] = [[ad; ae]; [bd; be]; [cd; ce]]
```

but you want

```
 f [a; b; c] [d; e] = [ad; ae; bd; be; cd; ce]
```

so you need to use an other iterator, *i.e.* :

```
 let f l1 l2 = 
   let res = List.fold_left (fun acc x ->
     List.fold_left (fun acc y -> (x * y) :: acc) acc l2
   ) [] l1 in
   List.rev res
```

or to flatten your result :

> ```
> val concat : 'a list list -> 'a list
> ```
>
> Concatenate a list of lists. The elements of the argument are all
>   concatenated together (in the same order) to give the result. Not
>   tail-recursive (length of the argument + length of the longest
>   sub-list).
>
> ```
>  val flatten : 'a list list -> 'a list
> ```
>
> Same as concat. Not tail-recursive (length of the argument + length of
>   the longest sub-list).

Comment: You are completely right. I was doing something really wrong and I was not getting there with the pen and paper. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: You're welcome. I took the liberty to edit your post to make it clearer. ;-) Welcome back to OCaml !

Answer (score 2):

Some [Core](http://janestreet.github.io/)-flavoured answers:

```
open Core.Std

let f1 l1 l2 =
  List.map (List.cartesian_product l1 l2) ~f:(fun (x, y) -> x * y)

let f2 l1 l2 =
  List.concat_map l1 ~f:(fun x -> List.map l2 ~f:(fun y -> x * y))

let f4 l1 l2 =
  let open List.Monad_infix in
  l1 >>= fun x ->
  l2 >>| fun y ->
  x * y
```

The last answer explicitly (and arguably the two other answers implicitly) makes use of the list monad, which this is a textbook use case of. I couldn't find the list monad in Batteries, which is possibly not so surprising as it's much less widely used than (say) the option or result monads.

Answer (score 1):

```
let f l1 l2 =  
  let multiply x = List.map (( * )x) l2 in
  l1 |> List.map multiply
     |> List.concat
```